# Any way to set Drupal theme settings per page?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a theme which has multiple theme options in its settings page. Is there a way to assign particular theme settings to specific Drupal paths?

Comment: The theme system should be able to do that, but AFAIK, no contributed theme has this built-in.  To do it, you need to create a subtheme of the theme - and hack the path dependencies it into that.

Comment: Sounds like subtheme is my only option!

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7, you can do this by taking advantage of the fact that theme settings are cached by [drupal_static()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7.x). See [theme_get_setting()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_get_setting/7.x). I think the same approach would work for Drupal 8 too, but haven't tried it.

```
// Implement HOOK_init.
// Here we override one of the Bootstrap theme settings.
function MY_MODULE_init() {
  // Only do this if we're actually on the relevant page.
  if ($_GET['q'] == PATH_TO_THE_PAGE) {
    // Override the Bootstrap theme setting 'Smart form descriptions (via Tooltips)'.
    // This because we want to display form input #description as text, not tooltip.
    // This will also affect any other forms on the current page, no easy solution for that.

    // Set the name of the theme we're interested in (the current theme in this case).
    $theme_name = $GLOBALS['theme_key'];    
    // Read the setting first to ensure that the drupal_static cache is populated.
    $setting = theme_get_setting('bootstrap_forms_smart_descriptions', $theme_name);
    // Get a reference to the cached settings.
    $cached_settings = &drupal_static('theme_get_setting');
    // Unset the 'bootstrap_forms_smart_descriptions' setting from the cache.
    unset($cached_settings[$theme_name]['bootstrap_forms_smart_descriptions']);
  }
}
```

I should add, this is arguably a bit of a hack, as it depends on the internals of drupal_static() and theme_get_setting() i.e. not documented API functionality - unless you consider the code to be the documentation :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the [ThemeKey Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey).

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional
>   properties exposed by other modules. In combination with Drupal's
>   theme inheritance you can easily achieve features like:
>
> - individually-styled channels
> - a front-page / "splash" screen
> - a date/time-selected Christmas theme
> - mobile themes for different auto-detected mobile devices
> - special themes for "limited" or "old" browsers
> - content, user, or role -specific themes
> - indicating your environment (production, staging, testing, sandbox, … )
> - testing your redesign safely on a live server
>
> And unlike other theme switching modules, ThemeKey should play well
>   with internal and external page caches, like Boost or Varnish, even
>   for anonymous users.

Comment: I think the OP actually wants different settings for a single theme, depending on path, not theme switching.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong is correct - I don't want to switch themes, but rather assign specific settings of said theme based on different paths. The only way I can see this possible with ThemeKey would be to replicate the theme in question and rename it, giving each replicate its own settings, and then assign that way. Not good.